# How to secure a parameter file as an available template in Azure Templates

Tags: azure, templates, parameters

I have been assigned a task to create an ARM template that deploys a VM and joins it to an Azure Automation DSC account, applying the correct configuration as it builds. On top of that I have been asked to upload it to the TEMPLATES portal in Azure so people can fill in a few parameters (machine name, v-net, admin password, and so on), click the build button and let it go and do its thing.

Azure templates: https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/Resources/resourceType/Microsoft.Gallery%2Fmyareas%2Fgalleryitems

I have finished the template and uploaded it to Azure, however there's an obvious issue where the template requires the following, and it has to be input by the user at the time of deployment:

```
"registrationKey": {
  "type": "securestring",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Registration key to use to onboard to the Azure Automation DSC pull/reporting server"
  }
},
"registrationUrl": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Registration url of the Azure Automation DSC pull/reporting server"
  }
}
```

This is asking for the registration key of my Automation DSC pull server and where to find it, something I don't want them to have to do/know.

Is there a way that would allow me to avoid them having to type this in without it being input into the template as plain text (such as a variable).

I have thought of using nested templates in a secure storage account with keyvault, but I'm sure at some stage it will require the storage account access key or a sas to get to it, which will need to be put in as a parameter by a user...

Any thoughts on this would be very helpful

Original DSC tempalte: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/dsc-extension-azure-automation-pullserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several options:

1. Use `listkeys` function in the template to retrieve those values (this has to be the best option), but there can be issues with this (across tenants, maybe something else).
2. you could try using key vault to get these values (no need for additional user input), but it might not work from the portal (which is the most likely case).
3. Create an HTTP Azure Function that you would consume as a nested deployment in your template. It would return these values. (the coolest one, but the hardest).

Comment: Just as you wrote that I was reading this: http://blog.tyang.org/2017/05/19/deploying-arm-templates-with-artifacts-located-in-a-private-github-repository/  Is this what you mean by your 3rd point?

Comment: yes, basically, but i'd advice against it, go for option one if you can. much simplier\sturdier

Comment: Can you use `listkeys` to access a previously deployed storage account and reference like I wish. From what I've read and understand, it's only used to retrieve keys of the storage account I am currently deploying in the ARM template,

Comment: thats a completely different question, you should start a new one, but the answer is yes, you can